# getting data from a cursor

Tags: java, android, android-cursoradapter

After running a query cursor hold data like this one

```
1 - R. Robert
 1 - F. Ahmed
 2 - M. Rahman
 2 - T. Banik
 3 - L. Morison
```

I want to get the data by specific id Like 1 and wnat to store it in an Array. I tried with this one

```
String [] Names = null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{

            if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                String namesAuth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
                Names[cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))] = namesAuth;
            }
      }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

I want a format like this one [R.Robert,F.Ahmed]. is this possible ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to filter the data in the cursor, construct a query with your required filters:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = new String[]{ /* Columns to include in the query */ };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,"_id=?", new String[]{"1"}, null, null, null);
```

then just iterate through your cursor

```
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME");
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            names.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work because you must initialize the array with a length and that code should(?) result in a `NullPointerException`.

You could instead use an `ArrayList` and add the string to it, like this.

```
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do{

        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            String namesAuth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
            names.add(namesAuth);
        }
  }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```